# C++ How to make derived class to take base class parameters automatically

Tags: c++, derived-class

When I change a value in base class and then, later on, create an object of the child class, child class created with an empty parameter instead of the changed value.
Is there a way to object of derived class with the parameters of the base class?

**Example:**

**Base.h**

```
class Base
{

class Child;

public:
    int number = 0;
    Child *chilObject;

    void Setup()
    {
         number = 5;
         childObject = new Child;
    }
};
```

**Child.h**

```
class Child :
    public Base
    {

    };
```

**main**

```
int main()
{
    Base base;   
    base.Setup();

    cout << base.number << " : " << base->chilObject.number << endl;
    cout <<  << endl;        
}
```

> Output: 5 : 0

I am simply asking if there is a way to make the derived class object to take Base class variables automatically.

Comment: You talk about "base" and "derived" classes, but I don't see any inheritance in your code.

Comment: Even assuming `Child` derives from `Base` then the `childObject` has no direct connection to its owning `Base` instance. This is not how you use inheritance

Comment: This is not inheritance, this is composition (of sorts). `class Child;` is a forward declaration of a class with no known relation to `Base`. `Child *chilObject;` declares a pointer to a `Child` - not inheritance.

Comment: I updated the question and added the class child, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I’m a bit confused about what you’re expecting to see here. The `chilObject` pointer points to a new `Child`. The default value for `number` is 0, and that’s what gets printed for that `Child`. Can you elaborate on what you want this code to do instead?

Comment: `childObject = new Child`: this new instance does not know about `number = 5`, it has its own `number`, which is 0 because `Setup` has not been called on `childObject`.

Comment: why is base even have a refrence to child class, only child should have a reference to base class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it is typically done in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{

public:

    int number = 0;

    virtual ~Base() = default;

    void Setup()
    {
        number = 5;
    }
};

class Child : public Base
{
    // number exists here because of inheritance.
};

int main()
{
    // Child object seen as Base object:
    Base* base = new Child;
    base->Setup();

    // Child object seen as Child object:
    Child* child = static_cast< Child* >( base );

    // Both share the same 'number' variable, so:

    std::cout << base->number << " : " << child->number << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Free memory taken by 'new'.
    delete base;

    return 0;
}
```

yields:

```
5 : 5
```

In real code, you would probably make `Setup` virtual and not cast though.